# dynamic SQL query while Upgrading from MSAccess 2003 to 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2013

My problem is that when I hard code the SQL statement (for testing), the app that this is being used in works normally. It fails when I try to use the value of a text box control on the parent form.

I have put msgbox to see the final  value of `Me.RecordSource` and SQL statements appear exactly the same. But the dynamically created one returns no records to the subform that uses this sub.

This issue occurred as we try to upgrade from MSAccess 2003 to MSAccess 2013

Where else do I need to check up on?

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
     Dim mytestOne As String
     Dim mytestTwo As String

mytestOne = "SELECT * FROM qryPacket_Log where EntityNoR =  " & Me.Parent.txtEntityNoSearch 

mytestTwo = "SELECT * FROM qryPacket_Log where EntityNoR = 123 " 

  ' Set the  RecordSource for this form

 'this does not work
 ' Me.RecordSource = mytestOne 

 'this works
  Me.RecordSource = mytestTwo 

End Sub
```

Comment: im sorry I meant Me.Parent.txtEntityNoSearch ... yes Hans it is fed to the parent form when it opens... not an msaccess expert... but  what is meant by the "link master field"? I am open to other ways of calling this dynamic sql as long as the subform's list view control populates correctly dynamically thanks so much

Comment: With the parent form open in Design View, select the subform control, and open its property sheet.  On the Data tab, find the "Link Master Fields" and "Link Child Fields" properties.  Do you have anything there already?  If not, try with that `txtEntityNoSearch` for Master and `EntityNoR` for Child.

Comment: now for multiple variables, can I say txtEntityNoSearch;txtEntityTypeSearch;txtSoOnAndSoForth for the Master Fields (corresponding values will be done also for the Child)?

Comment: Yes, you can specify multiple fields/controls in each of the Link Master and Child Fields properties.  (I hope that's what you meant.)

Comment: Yes I would like to specify multiple fields... so I typed in txtEntityNoSearch for Link Master Fields and EntityNoR for Link Child Fields. I tried a second field by typing  txtEntityNoSearch ; txtEntity (separated by semi-colon) ... If I try to use the Sub Field Linker dialog box that pops up when I click the 3 dots, it does not include the txtEntityNoSearch as part of the options...

Answer (score 2):

The subform datasource can be set by putting the control names of the parent textboxes in the "Link Master Fields" property. A corresponding field has to be set in the"Link Child Fields" property.

Example: txtEntityNoSearch;txtEntityTypeSearch for  Link Master Fields 
         EntityNoR;EntityTypeR  for Link Child Fields

Comment: Thanks for submitting this answer.  Please accept it when the system allows.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.